# NullPointerException when using Logback appender for Cloud Logging with standard App Engine Java 11

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I've followed [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/java#logback_appender_for) to write my application logs to Cloud Logging using the logback appender. My app is a Jetty web-server which I run by adding the following entry-point to my app.yaml file:

```
runtime: java11
entrypoint: 'java -cp "*" com.jettymain.Main webapp.war'
```

This is the added dependency in the pom file.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-logging-logback</artifactId>
        <version>0.122.1-alpha</version>
</dependency>
```

This the logback.xml file located in src\main\resources:

```
<!-- [START logging_logback_config] -->
<configuration>
  <appender name="CLOUD" class="com.google.cloud.logging.logback.LoggingAppender">
    <log>application.log</log> <!-- Optional : default java.log -->
    <resourceType>gae_app</resourceType> <!-- Optional : default: auto-detected, fallback: global -->
    <flushLevel>WARN</flushLevel> <!-- Optional : default ERROR -->
  </appender>

  <root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="CLOUD" />
  </root>
</configuration>
<!-- [END logging_logback_config] -->
```

This is how I'm using the logger:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Quickstart {
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Quickstart.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    logger.info("Logging INFO with Logback");
    logger.error("Logging ERROR with Logback");
  }
}
```

When I run the application this is the exception I get:

```
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@23:14 - RuntimeException in Action for tag [appender] com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at  at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingRpcFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:63)
    at  at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingRpcFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:55)
    at  at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getRpc(ServiceOptions.java:560)
    at  at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions.getLoggingRpcV2(LoggingOptions.java:129)
    at  at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingImpl.<init>(LoggingImpl.java:122)
    at  at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:46)
    at  at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:41)
    at  at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getService(ServiceOptions.java:540)
    at  at com.google.cloud.logging.logback.LoggingAppender.getLogging(LoggingAppender.java:275)
    at  at com.google.cloud.logging.logback.LoggingAppender.start(LoggingAppender.java:236)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction.end(AppenderAction.java:90)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callEndAction(Interpreter.java:309)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:193)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:179)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:62)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:165)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:152)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:110)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:53)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:75)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:150)
    at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:84)
    at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:417)
    at  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.logging.Slf4JLoggerFactory.<init>(Slf4JLoggerFactory.java:42)
    at  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory.newDefaultFactory(InternalLoggerFactory.java:44)
    at  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory.getDefaultFactory(InternalLoggerFactory.java:69)
    at  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory.getInstance(InternalLoggerFactory.java:92)
    at  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory.getInstance(InternalLoggerFactory.java:85)
    at  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.<clinit>(PlatformDependent.java:80)
    at  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.AsciiString.<init>(AsciiString.java:223)
    at  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.AsciiString.<init>(AsciiString.java:210)
    at  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.AsciiString.cached(AsciiString.java:1401)
    at  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.AsciiString.<clinit>(AsciiString.java:48)
    at  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.Utils.<clinit>(Utils.java:74)
    at  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.<clinit>(NettyChannelBuilder.java:82)
    at  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelProvider.builderForAddress(NettyChannelProvider.java:38)
    at  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelProvider.builderForAddress(NettyChannelProvider.java:24)
    at  at io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(ManagedChannelBuilder.java:39)
    at  at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:348)
    at  at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.access$1900(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:82)
    at  at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider$1.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:239)
    at  at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.create(ChannelPool.java:72)
    at  at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:249)
    at  at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.getTransportChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:227)
    at  at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:205)
    at  at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:136)
    at  at com.google.cloud.logging.spi.v2.GrpcLoggingRpc.<init>(GrpcLoggingRpc.java:148)
    at  at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingRpcFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:61)
    at  at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingRpcFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:55)
    at  at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getRpc(ServiceOptions.java:560)
    at  at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions.getLoggingRpcV2(LoggingOptions.java:129)
    at  at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingImpl.<init>(LoggingImpl.java:122)
    at  at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:46)
    at  at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:41)
    at  at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getService(ServiceOptions.java:540)
    at  at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler.getLogging(LoggingHandler.java:361)
    at  at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler.<init>(LoggingHandler.java:195)
    at  at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler.<init>(LoggingHandler.java:151)
    at  at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler.<init>(LoggingHandler.java:120)
    at  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$StaticContext.createInstance(ContextHandler.java:2881)
    at  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$Context.createInstance(ServletContextHandler.java:1299)
    at  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$StaticContext.createListener(ContextHandler.java:2892)
    at  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ListenerHolder.doStart(ListenerHolder.java:94)
    at  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:369)
    at  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1449)
    at  at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.startWebapp(JettyWebAppContext.java:328)
    at  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1414)
    at  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:910)
    at  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
    at  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
    at  at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:397)
    at  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)
    at  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
    at  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387)
    at  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at  at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:449)
    at  at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:310)
    at  at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunWarExplodedMojo.execute(JettyRunWarExplodedMojo.java:59)
    at  at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
    at  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
    at  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at  at com.google.cloud.logging.spi.v2.GrpcLoggingRpc.<init>(GrpcLoggingRpc.java:187)
    at  at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingRpcFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:61)
    at  ... 120 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder$NettyTransportFactory.<init>(NettyChannelBuilder.java:682)
    at  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.buildTransportFactory(NettyChannelBuilder.java:530)
    at  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder$NettyChannelTransportFactoryBuilder.buildClientTransportFactory(NettyChannelBuilder.java:188)
    at  at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(ManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:621)
    at  at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:264)
    at  at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:383)
    at  at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.access$1900(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:82)
    at  at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider$1.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:239)
    at  at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.create(ChannelPool.java:72)
    at  at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:249)
    at  at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.getTransportChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:227)
    at  at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:205)
    at  at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:136)
    at  at com.google.cloud.logging.spi.v2.GrpcLoggingRpc.<init>(GrpcLoggingRpc.java:148)
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to solve this issue would be to build a simple hello world application and try to achieve the grouping under the request logs.

Refer to the [link](https://github.com/googleapis/java-logging-logback/issues/94#issuecomment-727739327) to achieve this.

Here’s the workaround on how to group the logs under the request logs :

In the main file **SpringbootApplication.java**:

there is the following method:

```
 @GetMapping("/")
public String hello(@RequestHeader(value = "x-cloud-trace-context") String traceId) {
String[] parts = traceId.split("/"); 
String trace = parts[0];  
MDC.put("logging.googleapis.trace", String.format("projects/%s/traces/%s", "YOUR_PROJECT_ID", trace));
logger.info("Logging INFO with Logback" + trace);
logger.error("Logging ERROR with Logback" + trace);  
return trace;
```

}

I am getting the x-cloud-trace-context header by using spring mvc annotation and setting the first part of the trace in the MDC.
You can either keep this method or use a http request filter to abstract this part away, instead of doing it in each method. Also make sure to replace  "YOUR_PROJECT_ID" with your actual projectid.

The MDC property is then picked up by the TraceLoggingEventEnhancer defined in the logback.xml file which then makes sure that all logs show up under your request log.

**Note** : Google has provided a fix as mentioned [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/pull/1961). Make sure you are using the latest version for google-cloud-core.

Comment: My issue is that logback is not appending cloud logging correctly, the exception happens before printing the logs so it is not related to the grouping solution you provided. 

I'm using the latest versions for google-cloud dependencies, and the issue you mentioned is different.

Comment: Checkout the known [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138365527) Sometimes app log entries are not correlated with the request log. This happens the first time your app receives a request and any other time App Engine writes status messages to your app's log.

Comment: My issue is not that log entries are not correlated, the issue is that logs are not being shown at all due to the exception mentioned in the question.